# Php. Вывод массива

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Как можно вывести данные из массива в таком порядке как на картинке. Т.е. симметрично. Количество элементов может быть разным, но до 14. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не понял какой массив. Можно его в виде PHP? и в каком порядке вывести элементы?

Comment: @IvanBolnikh, массив любой, разницы нет. Порядок пронумерован на картинке